# jQuery show array in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html, text

I made an HTML page with some jQuery, but it doesn't do what I want it to do:

1. I want the jQuery to get the text of div 1.
2. Get rid of all the unwelcome chars.
3. Make an array of the text.
4. Show the array in the div 2.

1 and 2 are working and 3 should work as well.

I made this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<LINK href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var str = $("div.someText").text();
    var specialChars = "!@#$^&%*()+=-[]\/{}|:<>?,.";
    for (var i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\" + specialChars[i], 'gi'), '');
    }
    str = str.replace(/["'“”…]{1}/gi,".");
    str = str.replace(/[.*]{1}/gi," ");
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    var array = str.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        $("div.put").html(array[i] + "\n");
    }
})
</script>
<div class="someText">
Een kerel gaat met zijn pas gekochte hond naar de dierenarts. Eindelijk is hij aan de               
beurt en komt met zijn hond de behandelkamer binnen.......
“En?”, vraagt de dierenarts, “wat is het probleem?”. “Nou”, zegt de eigenaar van het beest,
“ik heb hem gekocht om te waken, maar elke keer als de bel gaat, dan gaat mijn hond in de hoek zitten”.
De dierenarts wrijft eens vakkundig over zijn kin en zegt tenslotte: “ja…dat doen boxers”.
</div>
<br />
<div class="put"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but I must do something wrong, becuase div 2 shows nothing.

Can anybody tell me why my code isn't working as expected?

Comment: Can you paste your html markup. Or bundle your example on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had various problems, but I have addressed them in this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/TzSLh/

1. `array.length()` should be `array.length`.  This was causing a fatal semantic error.
2. `str.split(str, ' ')` should be `str.split(' ')`.  The first argument is the string to split by.
3. `.html("string')` overwrites the HTML each time.  I have updated it with one method that allows you to append html content.  You could also use `.text` if it's just text.  If you want visible line breaks, use the CSS `white-space: pre`, or use `<br>` instead of `\n`.  You could also skip the loop and do `$("div.put").text(array.join("\n"));`

Answer (score 1):

In the line `var array = str.split(str," ");` you are using the wrong syntax for `str.split()`. If you're trying to split on spaces, you want `str.split(" ")`. I'm not sure what your code does with it currently, but I'm guessing it throws an error into the console.

Comment: Also, see the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    $("div.put").html(array[i] + "\n");
}
```

This code will loop through your array and each time set the innerHTML of every div with class "put" as the contents of an index in your array.

In the end it will have set that innerHTML to the contents of the last item in the array.  The rest will have been overwritten.

I suspect that you want to use [jquery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add each item to then end.  You could add it as a span tag for each one for instance.

I'm also not sure if your div actually has class "put".  That may or may not be an error.